# Why is my popup blocked on touch but not click using "pointerdown" listener?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've made a 'print page' function that when activated by clicking a button, opens a new window/tab and populates it with specific HTML and stylings that are different from the original window I'm activating the function from.

Everything works as expected when using a normal mouse click, however, when on a touch screen (or emulating a touchscreen), the new window is blocked.  The button is bound to the `pointerdown` event which intercepts both clicks and touches.

Can anyone explain what is going on here and why the `pointerdown` event reacts differently on a normal click versus touch, even though they're firing the same event?  I'm using Chrome (since our app uses the filesystem API, I can't test it on other browsers).

Normal click will open new window fine.  Turn on the "device emulator" and make sure it's set to 'touch' then try clicking the button again:

https://jsfiddle.net/7xmryg6j/

```
document.getElementById("print").addEventListener("pointerdown", printPage);

function printPage(e){
    console.log(e);
    window.open("", "printWindow");
}
```

EDIT:  I'm not looking for how to get around this using other event bindings, I'm trying to figure out why specifically `pointerdown` acts this way.

Comment: Does it actually say that a popup was blocked?

Comment: Yes, shows the alert/icon on the right side of the URL bar.  I'm gonna try and emulate it with some code when I get a second to better show what I mean.

Comment: Can you make a demo fiddle of the behavior?

Comment: Updated my question with code.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent browsers from blocking window.open calls, you have to be intercepting a 'click' event. The browser may block you from opening the window otherwise.

Example of opening a window that works with touches and clicks: https://jsfiddle.net/yyfe0824/5/

Here's the code:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<button class="sillyLink" data-url="http://www.google.com">Google</button>
<button class="sillyLink" data-url="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stack</button>
<button class="sillyLink" data-url="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/">MDN</button>

// JS
document.querySelectorAll('.sillyLink').forEach( node => 
node.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  window.open(e.target.dataset.url);
}))
```

Comment: Pointerdown is being called in both scenarios so there is no "click" event.  We are sticking to "pointerdown" for cross device consistency.

Comment: Click should still work across devices. It gets fired on touch screens.

Comment: This isn't answering my question.  I'm wondering why, when specifically binding to "pointerdown", does it work with a normal mouse click but not on touch even though the exact same event is being fired, not how to get around using "pointerdown".

Comment: If you're not intercepting a click event, the browser may block your request. Not that it will block, it just may block. You may not be able to use pointerdown for your purpose.